# Python 3 - Is there a way to keep the mouse inside the tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Python 3
Tkinter

Hey, I'm looking for something that don't allow the user to leave a window if a variable is true/false.

basicly, somethings that keeps the mouse inside the tkinter window

Comment: Just curious. What is the point of something like this. It seams like it would cause issues for the user especially if they have multi monitors set up or would like to use other programs at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, no. However you could monitor the mouse position with the `<Motion>` event and correct it every time it goes outside. How to correct it would depend on your OS; look into pyautogui for a crossplatform solution.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing right now. I just thought that there's a better way to do this. Thanks

Comment: That will be extremely annoying to your users.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force the mouse to stay in the window, though you can "grab" all of the mouse events, preventing the user from clicking anywhere but on your app. This is very dangerous as you can lock up your computer if your code has a bug in it.

See [How can I make area outside toplevel unclickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30405944/7432)